# Problem with state machine code generation

Tags: code-generation, state-machine, enterprise-architect

I'm testing EA code generation in v 15.2 for state machines containing substates.
I use "Example Model/Model Simulation/State Machine Models/Nested Traces" as eaxmple for C++ code generation.
When I generate code from "ExampleClass" I got different number of states activating "Use the New Sate Machine Tamplate" checkbox or not.

"New State Machine Template" results in

```
enum StateEnum 
{
    NOSTATE,
    ExampleClass_VIRTUAL_SUBMACHINESTATE,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_B,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_FINAL_2904,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_C,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_A,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_D,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_B_B2,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_B_B1,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_C_C1,
    ExampleClass_ENUM_NESTEDTRACES_C_C2
};
```

Where I can find all states and substates (e.g. A, B, B1, B2, ...)

But "Old State Machine Template" results in

```
enum StateType
{
    Nested Traces_B,
    Nested Traces_C,
    Nested Traces_Final,
    Nested Traces_D,
    Nested Traces_A,
    ST_NOSTATE
};
```

Where I can only find all main states (e.g. A, B, C, ...)

The used list in code generator template "Statemachine" is

```
$sStates = %EASLList="StateEnumerate" @separator=",\n" @indent="\t" @owner=$StateMachineGUID @collection="AllStates"%
```

that should deliver a collection of "AllStates" including sub states. EA User Guide says "All States within the StateMachine, including those within Submachine States".

To solve the problem I tried to access the submachine of a super-ordinate state.

Checking the "HasSubMachine" flag returns "true" but "SubMachine" ID is empty.

I like to use "Old State Machine Template" due to adapt code generation for existing state machine structure.

How is it possible to access the substates or to complete the state list?

Comment: There aren't too many EA power users here that actually use SM code gen. Consider posting on Sparx' forum with a link to here (since you can not easily include pictures oer there).